# Showing that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^{2}+3}dx = \frac{e^{-\sqrt{3}} \pi}{2 \sqrt{3}}$ via Contour Integration?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration

In the text "Function Theory of One Complex Variable" Third Edition, I'm inquiring if my proof of $\text{Proposition (1)}$ is sound ?

> $\text{Proposition (1)}$
>
> $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^{2}+3}dx = \frac{e^{-\sqrt{3}} \pi}{2 \sqrt{3}}$$

$\text{Proof}$

Assume that $R>1$ define $\gamma_{R}$ such that,

$$\gamma_{R}^{1}(t) =  t + i0 \, \,   \text{if} \, \, -R \leq t \leq R$$

$$\gamma_{R}^{2}(t) = Re^{it}  \, \text{if} \, \, \, \, \, \, 0\leq t \leq \pi.$$

$\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,  \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, $ [image]

Consider our choice $f$ and that,

$$\oint_{\gamma_{R}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^{2}+3} \, dz.$$

Clearly it's obvious that

$$\oint_{\gamma_{R}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^{2}+3}dz = \sum_{\psi = 1,2} \oint_{\gamma_{R}^{\psi}}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^{2}+3}dz.$$

It's trivial that,

$$\oint_{\gamma_{R}^{1}}e^{iz}/({z^{2}+3})dx \rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix}}{x^{2}+3}\operatorname{dx}$$

It's natural to claim that,

$$\Bigg|  \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty}\oint_{ \gamma_{R}^{2}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^{2}+3} dz  \Bigg|  \rightarrow 0. $$

Using the Estimation Lemma one can be relived that,

$$\bigg |\oint_{\gamma_{R}^{2}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^{2}+3} dz  \bigg | \leq \big\{\text{length}(\gamma_{R}^{2}) \big\} \cdot \sup_{\gamma_{R}^{2}}|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^{2}+3}|\leq \pi R \cdot \frac{1}{R^{2} - 3} \rightarrow 0 \, \text{as} \, R \rightarrow \infty$$

Thus,

$$ \operatorname{Re}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^{2}+3}dx =  \operatorname{Re} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{3}} \pi}{2 \sqrt{3}} = \frac{e^{-\sqrt{3}} \pi}{2 \sqrt{3}}.$$

However we need to consider that

$$\oint_{\gamma_{R}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^{2}+3} \, dz = 2 \pi i \sum_{j=1,2} \operatorname{Ind_{\gamma}} \cdot \operatorname{Res_{f}(P_{j})}$$

It's easy to observe that,

$$\oint_{\gamma_{R}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^{2}+3} \, dz = \big(2\pi i \cdot \frac{ie^{\sqrt{3}}}{2 \sqrt{3}}) = \frac{e^{-\sqrt{3}} \pi}{2 \sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: Where does $\frac1{R^2-1}$ come from?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo it's been fixed.

Comment: The length of $\gamma_R$...

Comment: The integral is over $\Bbb R$, or only over $\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$? (The contour goes from $-R$ to $R$. I was looking for a factor $2$ or $1/2$ on the one or the other side...)

Comment: Yeah I added the constant on the RHS side of the bound thanks for the nitpick and sorry for the typo.

Comment: More generally, $$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\cos(kx)}{x^2+1}\,\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\exp\big(-|k|\big)\text{ for all }k\in\mathbb{R}\,.$$
In your case,
$$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+3}\,\text{d}x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\cos(\sqrt{3}t)}{t^2+1}\,\text{d}t=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\,\exp(-\sqrt{3})\,,$$
where $t:=\sqrt{3}x$.  See, for example, the last two hidden boxes in the question of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870410/prove-int-limits-0-infty-dfrac-sinkxxx21-textdx-dfrac-pi.

Comment: @Batominovski is my initial proof incorrect ?  It seems look at the solution you linked me that  in Approach II and Approach 1 mine is incorrect and I should be relying on the fact that,   $$ \int_0^\infty\,\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+3}\,\text{d}x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\cos(\sqrt{3}t)}{t^2+1}\,\text{d}t=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\,\exp(-\sqrt{3}).$$ And from there consider that, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\oint_{\gamma_{R}}\frac{e^{\sqrt{3z}}}{z^{2} + 1}dz$$

Comment: I addressed some of the typo's that throw off the proof but I still feel like my solution may be incorrect may you provide some commentary @Batominovski. It seems the way I applied the Residue Theorem is correct and the bounds to prove that $$\Bigg|  \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty}\oint_{ \gamma_{R}^{2}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^{2}+3} dz  \Bigg|  \rightarrow 0.$$ are correct. it seems the gap I have to address using the Cauchy Integral Formula that, $$\oint_{\gamma_{R}^{1}}e^{iz}/({z^{2}+3})dx \rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix}}{x^{2}+3}dx.$$. It seems there are other ways to apply CA here :).

Comment: @Zophikel  Apart from some typos (which I fixed), your original proof looks almost fine.  I just put the link there for reference.

Comment: My comment is that there are two errors.  Note that $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\,\int_{\gamma_R^1}\,\frac{\exp(\text{i}z)}{z^2+3}\,\text{d}z=2\,\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+3}\,\text{d}x$$  as you probably forgot that $2\,\cos(x)=\exp(+\text{i}x)+\exp(-\text{i}x)$, and that $$2\pi\text{i}\cdot\left(\frac{\exp(-\sqrt{3})}{2\sqrt{3}\text{i}}\right)=\frac{\pi\,\exp(-\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt{3}}$$ is what you should get after applying the Residue Theorem.  Dividing this result by $2$, you will get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: All right I see the errors I should be able to correct them now that they have been spotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Batominovski's comments and insights I was able to note that there was errors in the original proof and a new one can be found below.

$\text{Proof}$

To proceed one must consider that,

> $$ \int_0^\infty\,\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+3}\,\text{d}x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\cos(\sqrt{3}t)}{t^2+1}\,\text{d}t=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\,e^{(-\sqrt{3})}$$

$t:=\sqrt{3}x$

Assume that $R>1$ define $\gamma_{R}$ such that,

$$\gamma_{R}^{1}(t) =  t + i0 \, \,   \text{if} \, \, -R \leq t \leq R$$

$$\gamma_{R}^{2}(t) = Re^{it}  \, \text{if} \, \, \, \, \, \, 0\leq t \leq \pi.$$

Consider our choice $f$ and that,

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,\oint_{\gamma_{R}}\,\frac{e^{(\sqrt{3}t)}}{z^2+1}\,\text{d}z $$

Clearly it's simple that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \oint_{\gamma_{R}}\frac{e^{(\sqrt{3}z)}}{z^2+1}dz = \sum_{\psi = 1,2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \oint_{\gamma_{R}^{\psi}}\frac{e^{(\sqrt{3}z)}}{z^2+1}dz.$$

Now it's imperative to claim that

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\,\oint_{\gamma_R^1}\,\frac{\exp(\sqrt{3}z)}{z^2+3}\,\text{d}z= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \,\int_{0}^{\infty}\, \, \frac{e^{(\sqrt{3}t)}}{z^2+1}\,\text{d}z  = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\,e^{(-\sqrt{3})}.$$

Now at this leg of our journey important to conjecture that,

$$\Bigg|  \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty}\oint_{ \gamma_{R}^{2}}\frac{e^{(\sqrt{3}z)}}{z^2+1}dz  \Bigg|  \rightarrow 0. $$

Thanks to Estimation Lemma we can be relived that,

$$\bigg |\oint_{\gamma_{R}^{2}} \frac{e^{(\sqrt{3}z)}}{z^2+3}dz  \bigg | \leq \big\{\text{length}(\gamma_{R}^{2}) \big\} \cdot \sup_{\gamma_{R}^{2}}|\frac{e^{(\sqrt{3}z)}}{z^2+3}|\leq \pi R \cdot \frac{1}{R^{2} - 3} \rightarrow 0 \, \text{as} \, R \rightarrow \infty.$$

Thus, taking

$$\operatorname{Re} \bigg( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\cos(\sqrt{3}t)}{t^2+1}\text{d}t \bigg) \,  = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\,e^{(-\sqrt{3})}$$

However we need to consider that

> $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \oint_{\gamma_{R}} \frac{e^{(\sqrt{3}z)}}{z^2+1}\, dz = 2 \pi i \sum_{j=1,2} \operatorname{Ind_{\gamma}} \cdot \operatorname{Res_{f}(P_{j})} $$

After a trivial calculation we have that,

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \oint_{\gamma_{R}} \frac{e^{(\sqrt{3}z)}}{z^2+1}\, dz =  2 \pi i + \operatorname{Res}\frac{e^{(\sqrt{3}z)}}{z^2+1}dz = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\,e^{(-\sqrt{3})}.$$

Comment: @Batominovski  I managed to get a correct solution using your suggestions in the comments section, is their an alternate approach without using the Residue Theorem ?

Comment: Rather than posting your (additional) work as an answer, better to edit it into the original post.

Comment: Actually this isn't (additional) work this is a proof addressing the errors that were spotted by @Batominovski